# Basic Batch Math Conversion-Missing Operand?

Tags: batch-file, math

So trying just a basic batch math script but always tell me missing operand can someone tell me why and how to fix it? i looked on here for similar problems and tried to match the syntax but got the same error. here is the script:

```
@echo OFF
set /p Choice=(a) Amps to Horse Power, (h) Horse Power to Amps:
set /p VOLTAGE=ENTER VOLTAGE:
if %Choice%==a (
  set /p AMPS=ENTER AMPS:
  set /a WATT=%VOLTAGE%*%AMPS%
echo power is:%WATT%
  REM   set /a HP=%WATT% / 746
  REM   echo %HP%
)
if %Choice%==h (
  set /p HP=ENTER HORSEPOWER:
  set /a AMPS=(( %HP% * 746 ) / %VOLTAGE% )
echo %AMPS%
)
```

Comment: Use either `set /a "AMPS=(( %HP% * 746 ) / %VOLTAGE% )"` or `set /a AMPS=^(^( %HP% * 746 ^) / %VOLTAGE% ^)`; the (closing) parentheses are the problem here as the command interpreter (`cmd`) considers the first `)` as the closing one of `if %Choice%==h (
`; so putting the parentheses in between `""` or escaping them by preceding `^` hides them from `cmd`...

Comment: Still the same issue :/ but good info to know about )

Comment: Ah, yes; remove all the surrounding `%` signs in all the `set /a` command lines (for instance, `set /a WATT=VOLTAGE*AMPS
`); otherwise, `%AMPS%` is evaluated to its value *before* the parenthesised block of code it is paced in is executed, which is nothing...

Comment: about escaping parentheses... though it may be not a good practice, as far as I've tested, you only need to escape the closing ones `set /a AMPS=(( %HP% * 746 ^) / %VOLTAGE% ^)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- The formula in command line `set /a AMPS=(( %HP% * 746 ) / %VOLTAGE% )` contain parentheses, which have got a special meaning for the command interpreter `cmd`: the first `)` is considered as closing parenthesis for the `if %Choice%==h (` command. To overcome this, put the entire arithmetic expression in between quotation marks like `set /a "AMPS=(( %HP% * 746 ) / %VOLTAGE% )"`, or escape the parentheses by the caret like `set /a AMPS=^(^( %HP% * 746 ^) / %VOLTAGE% ^)`.
- When you set/change a variable and read in the same parenthesised block of code, you will receive the value present before the entire block is executed. To overcome this, you could use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). However, in this specific case you can have it even simpler when you remove the enclosing percent signs within all `set /a` command lines, like `set /a WATT=VOLTAGE*AMPS`. The `set /a` command detects variable names on its own without the `%%`, which has got the great additional advantage that the received value is the one present at the moment the `set /a` command is executed rather than the one available before the block of code starts. The only thing left is the `echo` commands where you cannot omit the `%%` signs; but you can use the `call`-trick like `call echo %%AMPS%%`, where you force another parsing phase as soon as this command line is executed, resulting in the variable value available at that point of time (similar to the said behaviour of `set /a` and also delayed expansion).
- The `if` queries will fail if the user enters nothing and just presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, so place both comparison expressions in between quotation marks to avoid that: `if /i "%Choice%"=="a"`; I would also add the switch `/i` in order to make the comparison case-insensitive.
- The display messages of `set /p` sould be placed in between quotation marks in order to avoid trouble with special characters (like `(`, `)`) as well: `set /p Choice="(a) Amps to Horse Power, (h) Horse Power to Amps:"`.

---

Here is the code I would probably use, with the conversion `Amps to Horse Power` completed and with rounding (to the nearest integer) implemented for the divisions (because `set /A` supports signed 32-bit integer arithmetics only, so any potential fractional parts are dismissed):

```
@echo off
set /A "FACTOR=746"
set /A "ROUND=1" & rem set to `1` for rounding and to `0` otherwise;
set /P SEL="(a) Amps to Horse Power, (h) Horse Power to Amps: "
set /P VOLTS="Enter Voltage: "
if /I "%SEL%"=="a" (
    set /P AMPS="ENTER AMPS: "
    set /A "HP=(2*AMPS*VOLTS+ROUND*FACTOR)/(2*FACTOR)"
    call echo Horse Power is: %%HP%%
)
if /I "%SEL%"=="h" (
    set /P HP="Enter Horse Power: "
    set /A "AMPS=(2*HP*FACTOR+ROUND*VOLTS)/(2*VOLTS)"
    call echo Amps is: %%AMPS%%
)
```

Comment: AWESOME!! Thank you for your time and information with detailed explanations :D